# How using interface type instead of a class prevent allow changing the code

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

In an article about dependency injection [available here](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/dependencyinjection/67LX120413-Implementation-of-Dependency-Injection-Pattern-in-C), it says:

> Suppose your **Client** class needs to use a **Service** class component, then
>   the best you can do is to make your **Client** class aware of an IService
>   interface rather than a **Service** class. In this way, you can change the
>   implementation of the **Service** class at any time (and for how many
>   times you want) without breaking the host code.

How could I change the code - so lets assume that in the constructor, I will await IService instead of a reference to an instance of Service class. How does that help? If I change the name of methods etc., it will not work. If I change the inner workings of the method, it will still work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing nothing: by defining the parameter as an interface you are allowed to switch the implementations of the interfaces freely. Of course, these implementations still must need to meet the interface contract.

Comment: But so could I with classes (change content of methods etc.).

Comment: A class implies an implementation, so you will be forced to inherit an implementation. An interface gives you more freedom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:

```
public interface IFooObjectRepository
{
    IEnumerable<FooObject> Get();
}

public class FooObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class CsvFooObjectRepository : IFooObjectRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<FooObject> Get()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class InMemoryFooObjectRepository : IFooObjectRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<FooObject> Get()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class DbFooObjectRepository : IFooObjectRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<FooObject> Get()
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class FooObjectService
{

    private readonly IFooObjectRepository _repo;

    public FooObjectService(IFooObjectRepository repo)
    {
        this._repo = repo;
    }

    public void GetFooObjects()
    {
        IEnumerable<FooObject> = this._repo.Get();
        // Regardless of implementation of IFooObjectRepository, you'll get your IEnumerable<FooObject> from either your Csv, InMemory, or Db.
    }

}
```

This basically allows your FooObjectService class to use whatever implementation of IFooObjectRepository you desire.  You can switch in and out different implementations of IFooObjectRepository depending on your needs via your DI.

I don't think you're really missing anything, unless I'm not clear on what exactly it is you're asking about clarification on.